# Getting Field of study (disciplines) hierarchy information from Microsoft academic API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, evaluate, academic-graph

Is there any good way/workaround to get disciplines and subfields hierarchy information?

For example, **Optics** is Sub discipline of **Physics** and it got subfields like **Gemology, Optical physics**. Which intern might have another child field of studies? 
[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

First, get yourself a key to use the API using [these instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic/articles/sign-academic-knowledge-api/). Then use the [Evaluate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/evaluatemethod) to retrieve the fields of study. If you want to download the entire field graph use the query `Ty='6'`, manipulating Evaluate's `count` and `offset` parameters as appropriate. If you have a specific field of study ID in hand (e.g. from a paper) use the query `Id=xxx` (where xxx is the field of study Id) to get details about it. If you have a collection of identifiers, you can fetch them all together using a query like `Or(Id=xxx,Id=yyy,Id=zzz)`.

In either case you have to supply a list of attributes that you want returned by Evaluate. To get all the attributes, use `Id,FN,DFN,CC,ECC,FL,FP,FC`. The list of field names and contents is [here in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/fieldsofstudyentityattributes).

Addressing your question directly, `FP` and `FC` list the parent and children fields of study. Note that both fields are *lists*. This is because the structure is a directed graph, not a tree. Surprisingly, there are cycles in the graph, so don't go traversing recursively without checking for revisits!

You can play with the Evaluate API [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03/console) without having to write any code.

**Example:**

Using curl, this query returns the first 1000 (max limit of `evaluate`) field of studies. The result would contain name, id, parent id, parent name, child id and child name.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: API_KEY' \
  -d 'expr=Ty%3D'\''6'\''&attributes=Id%2CFN%2CFC.FN%2CFP.FN%2CFC.FId%2CFP.FId&count=1000'
```